# PHP, split .docx into paragraphs (PREG_SPLIT , "/\.\n/u")

Tags: php, preg-split

I am Trying to **read a docx** and **split it into parts first using the docxConversion class  ** 
The first function is read_docx

```
private function read_docx(){
    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';

    $zip = zip_open($this->filename);

    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;
    $zip_entry = zip_read($zip);
    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;
        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;
        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));             
        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);        
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $content = str_replace("</w:p>", "\r\n", $content);

    $pattern = "/(الفقرة\s[0-9]+\s)|(الأولى الفقرة)./u";//المادة\s*\d:

    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);               
    $splitted_para_arr = preg_split($pattern,$striped_content,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    return $splitted_para_arr;//striped_content;
}
```

> The Second Function is convert to text

```
    public function convertToText() {
      if(isset($this->filename) && !file_exists($this->filename)) {
        return "File Not exists";
    }
    $fileArray = pathinfo($this->filename);
    $file_ext  = $fileArray['extension'];        
        if($file_ext == "docx") {
            return $this->read_docx();            
        } else {
            return "Invalid File Type";
        }
  }
```

Then split each part into paragraphs using the following function

```
public function getParag($article){
    $splitted_para_arr = preg_split("/\.\n/u",$article,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);        
    return $splitted_para_arr;//striped_content;
}
```

> But the problem here is I can't get the paragraphs with the following pattern "/.\n/u"

Comment: `.\n` doesn't seem to be a valid sequence since you're using the windows style `\r\n` newlines. Maybe `.\r\n` will work, though a regex like `/\.\r?\n/` is probably better.

Comment: Thank you @apokryfos your suggestion works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deal with any kind of linebreak, use `\R`:

```
$splitted_para_arr = preg_split("/\.\R/", $article, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

`\R`     matches `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`

Comment: Just out of interest, why `\R` rather than `\v` ?

Comment: @CD001: `\v` matches more than `\R`, for example `FF` (form feed)